# Writing a counting program in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and coding in general and I need help with this problem.

Write a program that will take a string as input and will perform the following functions:

▪ Print the number(count) of spaces in the string

▪ Print the number(count) of lower case letters

▪ Print number of punctuation marks

Demonstrate how you would find the last space in a string

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? You will get more help if you provide some sample code and describe where you are hitting a wall.

Comment: This sounds more like you want a working example of what you listed above, then a problem your "stuck" on. Books, Google, Bing, and other online resources are your friend. If you come to Stack as your first resource, with a question that sounds like "do it for me" your not going to get any quality feedback, come to stack with an actual problem, and people will gladly help. Is this by chance for a class your hoping to skate through? Need someone to do the work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `len` together for counting things.  For example:

```
>>> import string
>>> s="This char -- or that one -- It's a Space."
>>> for k in [string.uppercase, string.lowercase, string.whitespace, string.punctuation]:
...     len(filter(lambda x: x in k, s))
... 
3
23
9
6
```

Note, the `string.uppercase, string.lowercase,` etc. values are defined in the `string` module, and can be used after you import the `string` module.  Each of them is a string value; for example:

```
>>> string.whitespace
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Note, in the above, >>> is the primary prompt from the python interpreter, and ... is a secondary prompt for an indented line.

Comment: I see and theses string.uppercase etc functions are already built into python and don't require being defined?

Comment: cool, thanks. I appreciate the explanation and your help.

Answer (score 2):

I will show you one example to give some ideas for you to play around with, and leave the others as exercise:

> Print the number(count) of lower case letters

```
>>> my_str = "Hello world!!"
>>> sum(1 for x in my_str if x.islower())
9
```

Comment: You could also just write `sum(x.islower() for x in my_str)`

Comment: That's right, but personally I find the fact that bool is a subclass of int to be an ugly wrinkle in python and I don't like to rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the characters in the string:

```
for char in my_string:
    # test if char is a space and if it succeeds, increment something
    # do the same for your other tests
    pass
```

The [`string` module](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html) has some constants that may be useful for you; in particular: [`string.punctuation`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.punctuation), [`string.lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.lowercase), and [`string.whitespace`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.whitespace). You can use [the `in` operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) to see if the character is in any of those sets of characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("type strint :")
space=" "
print(a.count(space))
lower=0
for w in a:
    if w.islower()==True:
        lower+=1
print(lower)
punc='!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'    
pmark=0
for p in a:
    if p in punc:
        pmark+=1
print(pmark)

# Demonstrate how you would find the last space in a string
if a[-1]== space:
    print("last space yes")
```